# Can you bind a key to minimize all open windows with AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, multiple-monitors

*I've disabled the standard WIN key shortcuts for a reason, so I can't for example invoke WIN+M or WIN+D which would have done something similar to what I want.*

I want to minimize all open windows on all monitors.

I've tried this myself in several ways, of which the most obvious seems to be:

```
#M::
  WinMinimizeAll
  return
```

This, however, only minimizes the windows that are on the main monitor, while the windows on other monitors are unaffected.

I've also tried looping through all windows gotten from WinGet and the like, but it seems to find processes that aren't really GUI windows and minimizing those too, resulting in weird grey box artifacts down by the taskbar that aren't clickable.

Is this doable and how? If I need another software to make it happen that could also be a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `DetectHiddenWindows On` in your script, WinGet is a good alternative:

```
SetWinDelay -1

$F1::MinimizeAll()
$F2::RestoreAll()

MinimizeAll(){
    DetectHiddenWindows Off
    WinGet, id, list
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        If NOT IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))
            continue
        WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (WinState = -1)
            continue
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue
        WinMinimize, ahk_id %this_ID%
    }
}

RestoreAll(){
    DetectHiddenWindows Off
    WinGet, id, list
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        If NOT IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))
            continue
        WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (WinState != -1)
            continue
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue
        WinRestore, ahk_id %this_ID%
    }
}

; Check whether the target window is activation target
IsWindow(hWnd){
    WinGet, dwStyle, Style, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if ((dwStyle&0x08000000) || !(dwStyle&0x10000000)) {
        return false
    }
    WinGet, dwExStyle, ExStyle, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (dwExStyle & 0x00000080) {
        return false
    }
    WinGetClass, szClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (szClass = "TApplication") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```